# Multiple Upload doesn't work in a relationship with subfields in laravel backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

have an issue with the upload_multiple when I try to use it from related model crud.

these are my models

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CaseComment extends Model
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
    use HasFactory;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\InlineCreateOperation;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'comment',
        'customer_case_id',
        'important',
        'documents'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'important' => 'boolean',
    ];

    public function customerCase()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CustomerCase::class);
    }

    public function setDocumentsAttribute($value)
    {
        $attribute_name = "documents";
        $disk = "public";
        $caseCode = CustomerCase::find($this->attributes['customer_case_id']);
        $destination_path = "documents/".$caseCode->casecode;
        $this->uploadMultipleFilesToDisk($value, $attribute_name, $disk, $destination_path);
    }
}

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Helpers\Helpers;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class CustomerCase extends Model
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'booking',
        'casecode',
        'status',
        'case_type_id',
        'user_id',
        'description',
        'resolution',
        'customer',
        'hotel_id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'state' => 'integer',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function hotel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Hotel::class);
    }

    public function casetype()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CaseType::class,'case_type_id');
    }

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany(CaseComment::class);
    }

    /**

     * Set the post title.

     *

     * @param string $value

     * @return string

     */

    public function setCasecodeAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['casecode'] = $this->attributes['booking'].Carbon::parse($this->attributes['created_at'])->timestamp;
    }


}
```

In my CustomerCaseCrudController I have this field:

```
$this->crud->addField(
            [
                'name'          => 'comments',
                'type'          => "relationship",
                'tab'           => 'Comments',
                'subfields'   => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'comment',
                        'label' => 'Comments',
                        'type' => 'textarea',

                    ],
                    [
                    'name'      => 'documents',
                    'label'     => 'Documents',
                    'type'      => 'upload_multiple',
                    'upload'    => true,
                    'disk'      => 'public'
                    ],
                    ]
            ]
        );
```

If I try to create a comment from the CustomerCase crud, the comment is created but the file is not uploaded and the path is not stored in the DB.

The I created a crud for the CaseComment in order to test and I added exactly the same upload_multiple field

```
CRUD::addField([   // Upload
            'name'      => 'documents',
            'label'     => 'Documentos',
            'type'      => 'upload_multiple',
            'upload'    => true,
            'disk'      => 'public'
        ]);
```

and works perfectly. So the mutator it's working, Also I can get the relation. Why it's not working from the CustomerCase crud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for raising the question. That's a known issue that is beeing addressed here: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/pull/4921

We expect by the end of the month at most have it merged as we have a few surprises for you guys regarding file uploads that goes along with that PR :)

Cheers